# Как перенести контекст в свойство класса

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно расширить класс, чтобы можно было делать так:

```
[1, 2, 3].property.containsKey('0')
```

Нужно именно для объекта проверять, есть ли ключ.

Особенность в том, что нельзя создать новый объект, нужно именно расширить базовый.

Я написал код ниже, но `this` оказывается равным `undefined`.

Как добиться правильной работы?

```
Object.prototype.property = {
   containsKey: (key) => {

   return key in this;
   }
};
```

Comment: не стоит удалять и задавать заново один и тот же вопрос

Comment: повторюсь: в текущем виде - никак.

Comment: ты уверен, что нужно именно `.property.containsKey` а не просто `containsKey`? Что должно возвращаться при обращении к `.property`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде, добиться "правильной" работы не получится, так как нет возможности получить объект, по свойству.

Поэтому самое простое решение - убрать лишнюю прослойку `.property`

```js
Object.prototype.containsKey = function(key) {
  return key in this;
};
console.log([1, 2, 3].containsKey('0'))
```

---

Если прослойка зачем-то нужна, то можно объявить `getter` с помощью [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'property', {
  get: function() {
    return {
      containsKey: (key) => key in this
    };
  }
});
console.log([1, 2, 3].property.containsKey('0'))
```